# UISegmentedController not changing UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I am new to this and could use some help. I have a 5 segment controller but only the first button is acknowledged. The other buttons do not seem to work. I have tried this code both under

```
-(IBAction)segmentbutton:(id)sender
```

and

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

also as you can tell the last segment was a different code i tried with no luck.
If there is a better way to format this that you know of, feel free to share!

```
if (Selector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2fire.png"];
}
if (Selector.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2"];
}
if (Selector.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
    Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball70color"];
}
if (Selector.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {
    Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2b.png"];
}
if (Selector.selectedSegmentIndex == 4) {
    [Ball setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"ball2r.png"]];
}
```

Comment: 0-> @"ball2fire.png 1-> " @"ball2" set @"ball2.png"; 2-> @"ball70color" to @"ball70color.png" i think you mistake is image are available or not? check it @Bryan Keller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it looks like you've put the code to change the picture within your `viewDidLoad` method? This is wrong. the viewDidLoad is only called once, when the view is loaded. Your code needs to go within the IBAction method for your segmentedControl like so -

```
-(IBAction)segmentbutton:(UISegmentedControl)sender{

   if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
     Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2fire.png"];
   }
   if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
     Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2"];
   }
   if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
     Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball70color"];
   }
   if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {
     Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2b.png"];
   }
   if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 4) {
     [Ball setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"ball2r.png"]];
   }
}
```

**Please note, when your segmented control was CTRL dragged from view to your class file to create a SegmentedControl IBAction, select that the object TYPE is a `UISegmentedControl` object, as opposed to `id` In this way you can use the properties of that object, as you will notice within each if statement the code can be changed to** `if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex....`

See picture -

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for such a great answer!